# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | { [key: string]: Json | undefined; } | Json[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, supabase-database

I'm using supabase as the db for my react app. To store data, I have state in the react app. In the event that this is a fresh user and has no data, I don't want to assign null or undefined in the state, so I add in a default value like:

```
const [educationList, setEducationList] = useState(
    formData?.education ?? [
      {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * PROJECT_MAX),
        degree: "",
        university: "",
        startYear: "2023",
        endYear: "2023",
        isCurrentUni: false,
      },
    ]
  );
```

I have a method to edit the degree field in the education list object:

```
const editDegree = (id: number, value: string): void => {
    let temp = educationList;
    for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
      const element = temp[i];
      if (element.id === id) {
        element.degree = value;
      }
    }

    setEducationList([...temp]);
  };
```

Typescript doesn't like this method, and throws an error saying:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | { [key: string]: Json | undefined; } | Json[]'.
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string'
```

In the Json type generated by supabase, it mentioned that it can have objects of type Json, along with some primitives. So why is typescript complaining? And why is it saying id does not exist on type string?

Types generated by supabase:

```
export type Json =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | null
  | { [key: string]: Json | undefined }
  | Json[];

export interface Database {
  public: {
    Tables: {
      user_profile: {
        Row: {
          byline: string | null;
          details: string | null;
          education: Json[] | null;
          experience: Json[] | null;
          id: number;
          location: string | null;
          name: string | null;
          projects: Json[] | null;
          skills: string[] | null;
          user_id: string | null;
          user_slug: string | null;
        };
        Insert: {
          byline?: string | null;
          details?: string | null;
          education?: Json[] | null;
          experience?: Json[] | null;
          id?: number;
          location?: string | null;
          name?: string | null;
          projects?: Json[] | null;
          skills?: string[] | null;
          user_id?: string | null;
          user_slug?: string | null;
        };
        Update: {
          byline?: string | null;
          details?: string | null;
          education?: Json[] | null;
          experience?: Json[] | null;
          id?: number;
          location?: string | null;
          name?: string | null;
          projects?: Json[] | null;
          skills?: string[] | null;
          user_id?: string | null;
          user_slug?: string | null;
        };
        Relationships: [
          {
            foreignKeyName: "user_profile_user_id_fkey";
            columns: ["user_id"];
            isOneToOne: false;
            referencedRelation: "users";
            referencedColumns: ["id"];
          }
        ];
      };
    };
    Views: {
      [_ in never]: never;
    };
    Functions: {
      [_ in never]: never;
    };
    Enums: {
      [_ in never]: never;
    };
    CompositeTypes: {
      [_ in never]: never;
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: I would suspect that because you're not explicitly typing the stateful variable you're using, it is trying to infer the type of `educationList`. It's not clear to me what shape `formData` may have, so could it be inferring the type as that rather large union? In which case, the eventual `element.id === id` check would be problematic since the inferred type can't guarantee an `id` field to be present.

Incidentally, `Math.random` is probably a bad idea for generating UUIDs (see [here](https://hackernoon.com/using-javascript-to-create-and-generate-uuids)). Also, why store the years as strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well typescript is complaining because JSON can be anything, for example someone will write null or string to database. So you have to assure Typescript that education is object. For example you can add more checks in your method like this(very straightforward code, needs improvements):

```
const editDegree = (id: number, value: string): void => {
        educationList.forEach((element) => {
            if (element === null) {
                return
            }

            if (typeof element === 'string') {
                return
            }

            if (typeof element === 'number') {
                return
            }

            if (typeof element === 'boolean') {
                return
            }

            if (Array.isArray(element)) {
                return
            }

            if (element.id === id) {
                element.degree = value
            }
        })

        setEducationList([...educationList])
    }
```